# How to read the text in the shape use python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

How to read the text in the shape use python-docx?

I have tested the inline_shapes, which is an empty array.

The definition of inline_shape has no text either. 
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shape.html#docx.shape.InlineShapes

How could I read the **name** from the following docx?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python-docx does not support the arbitrary drawing at this moment.

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/shapes.html